# Page load event outside InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I need to open an external page from my Phonegap app. I need to make it compatible with at least Android and iOS.

I have this code to open the external page

```
            **var ref = window.open('http://mysite.com/', '_blank', 'location=no');**
            lastPageLoaded = ref;
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
                try {
                    alert('executing...');
                    var retVal = lastPageLoaded.executeScript(
                        {
                            code: "alert('got here!');"
                        }, function () {
                        });
                }
                catch (exception) {
                    alert(exception);
                }
            });
```

I also have this in my config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The code above invokes the InAppBrowser an correctly opens my external page. BUT, the InAppBrowser is not in fullscreen mode which is not good for my app.

I noticed that if I make a slight change to the bolded (that is, the text decorated with ** ) line above to this:

```
var ref = window.open('http://mysite.com/', **'_self'**, 'location=no');
```

than InAppBrowser is not invoked but the external page opens in full mode, as my entire app is, which is good!

However, adding the event listener won't work:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event)
```

I mean, my code never gets to execute this line:

```
code: "alert('got here!');"
```

Seems logical because now I am not running under InAppBrowser context, but I need one of two solutions:
1. Make InAppBrowser run in fullscreen mode and keep my existing event handler
2. Find a similar event to hook to so I can invoke the script on the loaded external page.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Do you see the alert when you run with the target set to `_blank` like in the first example? Even though the app is not in fullscreen mode, does it execute your script? If not I think the problem is with `executeScript()` otherwise it is with `executeScript()` when target is `_system`. Also, are you seeing anything in your logs?

Comment: @MBillau yes, in the first scenario using _blank I can see the alert. it works as expected, the problem in this scenario is that my app leaves the fullscreen state. In the second scenario, if I place anything that _blank in there, the app beautifully stays in fullscreen but I get no alert. how can I check my logs? I am using build.phonegap.com to build my app and I an using hydration for automaticly updating the app